# Change style of textarea based on checkbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, checkbox

I would like to change the style of a textarea if a checkbox is checked and the textarea is empty. A red border should appear.

If the textarea is not empty and the checkbox is not checked, the border should disappear.

I have tried something like this, but the border is shown even when the textarea is not empty.

```
<input style="display: inline;" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">

<textarea name="" id="" cols="5" rows="3" ng-model="comments" ng-disabled="request.disableTransfer" ng-pattern="/^[0-9A-Za-z]*$/" ng-required="checked"></textarea>
```

This is the css part :

```
textarea.ng-invalid {
    border: 3px solid #cc4b37 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as per your requirements...

*1. If a checkbox is **checked** and the textarea is **empty**. A red border should **appear**.*

*2. If the textarea is not **empty** and the checkbox is **not checked**, the border should **disappear**.*

Could you point the error ??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
 textarea.ng-invalid {
    border: 3px solid #cc4b37 !important;
}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'">

<input style="display: inline;" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">

<textarea name="" id="" cols="5" rows="3" ng-model="comments" ng-disabled="request.disableTransfer" ng-pattern="/^[0-9A-Za-z]*$/" ng-required="checked"></textarea>
 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
  .invalid-input {
    border: 3px solid #cc4b37 !important;
}  



<textarea ng-class="{'invalid-input': (!comments || comments == '' )&& checked }" id="" cols="5" rows="3" ng-model="comments"
 ng-disabled="request.disableTransfer" ng-pattern="/^[0-9A-Za-z]*$/" ng-required="checked"></textarea>
```